# Can an Excel (*.xls, *.xlsx) file be saved with UTF-8 Encoding?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a csv file (UTF-8 encoded) which contains certain Japanese characters. I want to save it as an *.xls file. I use the following VBA code for it

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\to\file.csv")
wb.SaveAs("C:\Path\to\file.xlsx", xlWorkbookDefault)
```

Problem is when I check the encoding of the *.xlsx file, it is `ANSI`. So I tried this

```
wb.SaveAs("C:\Path\to\file.xlsx", xlUnicodeText)
```

The encoding here is `UCS-2 LE BOM` and the characters don't appear properly.

How do I save it as an *xls or *.xlsx file which has `UTF-8` encoding?

Comment: Try `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.

Comment: Try not opening CSV with `Workbooks.Open` (which I didn't even know was possible on text files) but with `QueryTables`. Plenty of SO posts on this method. Do the characters appear properly after CSV import?